# MVVM event celleditend. не обновляются данные

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

код компонента

```
       <DataGrid Name="dgMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Margin="10"
              ColumnWidth="100"
              SelectionUnit="Cell"
              dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.ColumnHeadersSource="{Binding ColumnHeaders}"
              dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowHeadersSource="{Binding RowHeaders}"
              dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ParseValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

код команды

```
 public ICommand ParseValue { get; }

    private void Eval()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
            if (Data[i][j] != null)
            {
                Data[i][j] = RM(Data[i][j]);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data));
            }
    }

    private string RM(string dataString)
    {
        return dataString.Remove(0,1);
    }
```

проблем сразу несколько:

1. данные изменяются, но на форме изменения не отображаются
2. каждый раз оббегать весь string[][] Data очень не интересная идея
3. не понятно как получить конкретно ту ячейку, которая изменилась

Comment: А вы бы привязывали ваш `DataGrid` не к жутко неудобному двумерному массиву, а к `ObservableCollection` объектов, реализующих `INotifyPropertyChanged`, вот и не было бы проблем. Вы сами себе создаёте неудобства.

Comment: ObservableCollection<string[][]> Data? и как я с его помощью узнаю, какую я ячейку изменил?

Comment: Нет, что вы. Во-первых, строки таблицы должны соответствовать осмысленным объектам. То есть вы заменяете массив строк `string[]` на объект, название которого должно соответствовать смыслу ваших данных. А сами эти объекты упаковываете опять-таки не в массив, а в `ObservableCollection<...>`. Стало яснее?

Comment: @VladD, а это то и суть, что осмысленных объектов нет. есть двумерный массив строк

Comment: Окей, а зачем вам тогда именно DataGrid? Что вы хотите сделать с ними, какие операции нужны?

Comment: @VladD да ничего особенного я с ним делать не хочу. просто при вводе данных в датагрид я хочу их слегка корректировать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете как-то странно. Давайте попробуем проще и без внешних модулей.

Для начала, вам не нужен жутко неудобный `DataGrid`, перейдём лучше к нормальному `ItemsControl`'у. Если мы хотим строки и столбцы, сделаем вложенность.

Получаем такой XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Во внутреннем `ItemsControl`'е мне пришлось переопределить `ItemsPanel`, чтобы элементы показывались горизонтально.

Теперь, почему у нас вдруг привязка `<TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>`? Откуда берётся `Value`? Дело в том, что если мы просто привяжемся к `string[][]`, вашим `DataContext`'ом внутренней клетки будет просто `string`, массив разберётся на отдельные строки. При обновлении строки обновится `DataContext`, но не массив. Значит, нам нужен контейнер для строк. Чтобы не менять структуру массива `string[][]`, пусть контейнер на него ссылается.

Получаем такую вспомогательную структуру:

```
class StringHolder
{
    public string[][] data;
    public int i, j;
    public string Value
    {
        get => data[i][j];
        set => data[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

Наша VM будет выглядеть так:

```
class MainVM
{
    string[][] data;
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<StringHolder>> Data =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length)
                  .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, data[i].Length)
                                         .Select(j => new StringHolder()
                                                      { data = data, i = i, j = j }));
    public MainVM(string[][] data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

```
// давайте чем-то заполним наш массив
var data = new string[5][];
var words =
    ("Если я что-нибудь в чём-нибудь понимаю, то дыра — это нора, " +
     "а нора — это Кролик, а Кролик — это подходящая компания, " +
     "а подходящая компания — это такая компания, где меня чем-нибудь " +
     "угостят и с удовольствием послушают мою Ворчалку.")
    .Split()
    .Where(w => w.Any(char.IsLetter))
    .Select(w => w.Trim('.', ','))
    .ToList();
var ysize = words.Count / data.Length;
int widx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = new string[ysize];
    for (int j = 0; j < ysize; j++)
        data[i][j] = words[widx++];
}

MainVM vm = new MainVM(data);
```

Результат:

[image: нора — это Кролик]

Теперь, если вы хотите добавить какую-нибудь логику, вам нужно положить её в сеттер свойства `Value` класса `StrignHolder`, и не забыть реализовать в нём `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: а можете скинуть проект? ато я как не пытаюсь повторить либо при компиляции ошибки, либо во время выполнения

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr: Вот вам весь код в проекте: https://pastebin.com/86UZTUSu